# UIActionSheet at the Top of the Screen

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiactionsheet

I want to display UIActionSheet at top of the screen ,is it possible?

```
 private UIActionSheet _imageOptionsActionsheet;

 imageOptionsActionsheet = new UIActionSheet("Select Option", null, "Cancel", null, new string[] { "Images Choosen", "My List", "Image Library", "Upload" });
```

I am trying the above code it is displaying bottom of the screen, but i want at the top of screen

Comment: Do you need to support iOS 7?

Comment: I wasn't asking about iPhone models, but the OS version. The problem is, that the code you currently use is deprecated in iOS 8.

Comment: but, in my Xamarin.Ios supports the above code